# Flutter Drawer widget icon color and size

Tags: flutter, colors, size, drawer

I want to change the default color and size of the Drawer widget icon in flutter.
I beleive that it's possible but I just can't find how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

1. **IconThemeData** class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconThemeData-class.html) for *Defines the color, opacity, and size of icons.*
2. **IconTheme** class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconTheme-class.html) for *Controls the default color, opacity, and size of icons in a widget subtree.*

   ```
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Your Title'),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        size: 40,//change size on your need
        color: Colors.red,//change color on your need
      ),
    ),
    drawer: Drawer(),
   );
   ```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Read this document to know more about Drawer Widget

Once check this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-dart-programming)